# Method of an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to know what is the method (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) of an ajax request in Javascript or Jquery?

I went through the docs but I couldn't get a solution. My aim is to set headers if the ajax request is not of GET method.

Comment: What sort of reference do you have to the request? Is it an XMLHttpRequest instantiation, or what?

Comment: You want find when and where?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, an XMLHttpRequest instance.

Comment: @CertainPerformance
I wanted to add this header for all ajax requests which are not of GET calls. Currently, I'm using following code: 

`$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) { xhr.setRequestHeader(SOME_HEADER, SOME_VALUE); });`

which adds this header for all ajax calls, including the ones with GET calls.

Comment: It doesn't look possible to modify the method of an XMLHttpRequest that has already been `open`ed. (if the method has already been defined on it) But this really sounds like an XY problem rather than something that you should be trying to achieve.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not modifying the method. I just want to check what is the method of XMLHttpRequest, so that I can set a header accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    if(options.type != "GET") {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(HEADER, VALUE);
    }
});
```

*options* gives the *type* of the request that's being made.

Thank you everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jQuery for making AJAX calls, recommend using either native `fetch` or in case you need to support older browsers you can use https://github.com/github/fetch.

By default AJAX calls will be `GET` calls. If you want to use another HTTP method, then you need to set the `method` as an option. For example using native `fetch`

```
fetch('someURL', {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
});
```

Another good read is https://davidwalsh.name/fetch.

This is while making the ajax call. If you want to what was the original call made from the `response` you get, unless the server explicitly sets the value in the header, I don't think you will be able to figure that out.

Comment: I wanted to add this header for all ajax requests which are not of GET calls.
Currently, I'm using following code:

`$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(SOME_HEADER, SOME_VALUE);
});`

which adds this header for all ajax calls, including the ones with GET calls.